# Copy Unique values from one data frame to another in R

Tags: r

I have two data frames with totally different column names and values.

Example :

Data Frame 1 ->

```
company value
A       10
B       11
A       9
```

Data Frame 2 ->

```
id     value2
Q       7
W       8
E       9
```

This question has several parts that I want to achieve:

1. Extract the unique values of COMPANY column from
   data frame 1 based on the COMPANY column(Unique companies)
2. Copy the unique values obtained above into a NEW
   COLUMN in Data Frame 2 RANDOMLY (only company field)
3. Merge the two data frames based on the unique value
   column.(This is only for testing, hence why I need this step)

All help is appreciated!!
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you just mean something like `df2$newcol <- sample(unique(df1$company), nrow(df2), replace=TRUE)` ?

Comment: The unique number of companies in df1 has be >= the number of rows in df2 do to the second part

Comment: @Headpoint - depends if you're sampling with replacement or not. > or < is possible.

Comment: @thelatemail, ture, but then they are not unique...

Comment: @thelatemail thank you for your input. I am quiet new to this, so is it possible if you can explain what your line of code does?

Comment: `unique()` finds unique values in a vector. `sample()` takes a random sample. If `replace=TRUE`, the same values can be selected multiple times. If `replace=FALSE`, each value will only be selected 1 time maximum.

Comment: @Headpoint Does it have to be >= ? Because i just want to use the unique values as samples in the data frame 2

Comment: @T.S Say you have 3 unique companies in df1. In df2 you have 5 rows. Then what do you do?

Comment: @thelatemail Thanks a lot for the explanation. Let me give it a try

Comment: @Headpoint can we keep on adding companies ? So when df2 reaches the 3rd row with the first 3 rows of df1, can we start the 4th row of df2 again with any random row from df1?

Comment: @thelatemail It worked like a charm. Thank you so much. Also the final step regarding the merge, can i use "dt1 = merge(dt1,dt2,by.x = "df1_column", by.y = "df2_column")"

Comment: @T.S - yep, though I would use `dtnew = ...` rather than overwriting `dt1`

Comment: @thelatemail Awesome! thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
company <- unique(df1$company)
df2$new_column <- sample(company, nrow(df2), replace = TRUE)
```